# Issue : Create a new alias. Leave the existing alias functioning

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I tried to save my old alias in Drupal 7 using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

I am selecting the "Create a new alias. Leave the existing alias functioning." in Settings. But, It deletes the old URL. Only current alias is working.

Can anybody suggest on this how to reproduce it.

Comment: try to clear cache from admin as well as browsers caching.

Comment: @NishantP, Yes. I cleared all the cache and also tested in database. Only recent Alias is saved in DB. Any other suggestion. Thank you.